# Set up WebRTC connection with one-way signalling?

Tags: javascript, webrtc, p2p

I want to write a p2p web application that utilizes WebRTC for communication between two parties with no signalling server.  This way the webapp can simply be hosted on Github pages with no backend necessary.

I'd like for User A to be able to simply share a link containing the WebRTC offer information encoded in the URL that User B can open in his web browser for the two clients to be connected.

However, it seems WebRTC signalling expects a two-way handshake to occur between User A and User B. Is it possible to instead pregenerate the answer used by User B on User A's side so that only one-way communication is required, as illustrated below?

[image]

Here is a sample SDP offer and answer I created from a [WebRTC demo](https://mac-blog.org.ua/b841951c3b09244c7e1f6bde1920d6de/index.html) for reference:

## Example Offer

```
v=0
o=- 3607826526481542571 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE 0
a=extmap-allow-mixed
a=msid-semantic: WMS
m=application 61287 UDP/DTLS/SCTP webrtc-datachannel
c=IN IP4 166.175.56.10
a=candidate:2170208137 1 udp 2113937151 8a09da87-6d13-4883-bc97-d249540a671f.local 36719 typ host generation 0 network-cost 999
a=candidate:2264690881 1 udp 1677729535 166.175.56.10 61287 typ srflx raddr 0.0.0.0 rport 0 generation 0 network-cost 999
a=ice-ufrag:RV+T
a=ice-pwd:00CC7oTlMuohBi0DakoBs8Re
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 CF:EC:98:60:EF:E3:8F:26:C4:F3:21:EF:FB:63:D2:9E:EC:38:EC:EA:E1:90:59:52:63:50:2D:C4:39:FD:90:D0
a=setup:actpass
a=mid:0
a=sctp-port:5000
a=max-message-size:262144
```

## Example Answer

```
v=0
o=- 1158795722672034880 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=group:BUNDLE 0
a=extmap-allow-mixed
a=msid-semantic: WMS
m=application 9 UDP/DTLS/SCTP webrtc-datachannel
c=IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=ice-ufrag:fN/S
a=ice-pwd:wuR39sEclXnPhO7IsSAg1lmG
a=ice-options:trickle
a=fingerprint:sha-256 C6:0E:B8:C8:A5:A0:C7:25:A6:66:DD:B1:D9:B4:7E:5A:81:4C:AC:5B:06:9D:9E:9F:CB:9E:34:32:EC:5C:A4:1E
a=setup:active
a=mid:0
a=sctp-port:5000
a=max-message-size:262144
```

Comment: What about this? https://peerjs.com/